# How do I create a symbolic link to a UNC Path in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, symbolic-link, unc

I have a workstation with Windows XP and I need to make a symbolic link or mount a UNC Path like a local Drive. I need the same behavior that produces M-Daemon tools when you mount an .iso File but with a remote directory. This is because I have a software client that perform several task but only with local drives and directorys.

The remote UNC path is a NAS server, thats the why I need to perform all the tasks from a workstations.

Answer (score -1):

First mount as a drive letter, say m:\ and you want m:\target_folder

Second run

```
mklink /D C:\symbolic_folder_name m:\target_folder
```

Voila